# Why I can't access this property in class?

Tags: objective-c

[image]

Please refer to this image, I have declared property matchResult, why couldn't I access it from its instance?

The other property "score" works, why?

The code runs in iOS6 environment.

Please open image in a new tab if you couldn't see it clearly.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have defined the property in the implementation file "CardMatchingGame.m", 
using a *class extension*. That means that the property is only available in the `@implementation` block of this class.

To make the property accessible from other classes, move the declaration to the public `@interface` in "CardMatchingGame.h".

Comment: AFAIK you cannot declare properties in class extensions.  This is not an extension of a 3rd party class. (Plus there is no category given). But it is some sort of "private" interface because it is declared in the .m file not in the public .h file.

Comment: @HermannKlecker: You cannot declare instance variables in class *categories*. But you can declare instance variables and properties in class *extensions*. - A class extension *is* an interface private to the implementation block. - See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3.

Comment: It’s a class continuation, in Obj-C parlance.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: You are right. But without the source code it is difficult to guess the reason.

Comment: As you can see my answer, that was one possiblitly by seeing all, but someone didn't like that, later OP confirmed that he tried that too.

Comment: Good point. There is probalby another `score` property in a superclass or in the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

It is declared within the .m file and therefore not visible from "external". It does not matter that you access it from a method of the same class. You acces an external interface by referring to `self.game.matchResult`. 
If `game` equals `self` then you could access self.matchResult. But I do not think it does because you fetch self.game from the array self.cardButtons.

So, you will either use `self.matchResult` if you are referring to `self` or you will have to move the property to the interface definition within the .m file.